# Error response from daemon: manifest for myregistry.io/image:latest not found

Tags: docker

When I try to pull from my container registry like so:

```
docker pull myregistry.io/image
```

I get error

> Error response from daemon: manifest for myregistry.io/image:latest not found

If I try using exact build number (how I tag in in CD pipeline) then it works:

```
docker pull myregistry.io/image:123
```

How do I get the latest tag working?  (I am using Azure Container Registry)

Comment: Just add the latest tag when you build and push you image to azure cr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest tag is not added automatically to an image by all registries. You'll have to tag it explicitly after building the image